# I over-wrote my xorg.conf with Nvidia-settings and lost my XFCE settings

Tags: nvidia, xorg, xubuntu, xfce

I changed some monitor resolution things with the Nvidia tool (saved to /etc/ .. xorg.conf) and when I restarted XFCE I had lost all styling of taskbar, icons, defaults fonts etc..

What can I do to either bring the old xorg.conf back or restore my settings otherwise? (I tried using the settings manager but to no avail)

http://pastebin.com/U1mgtcQe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nvidia tool` normally makes a copy of your xorg.conf. I would check if it doesn't exist in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.old`

Comment: cool, it worked, do you know where should I save if I want to avoid this situation?

Comment: xorg.conf just manages the configuration of your graficcard and monitor setup. All styling of your windows are managed somewhere else. Probably /home/george/.gconf/somethinghere or /home/george/.wmaker/somethinghere. I actually don't know since I'm not using xfce. To backup your xorg.conf you can just copy it somewhere like this: sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/george/Desktop/xorg.conf.backup.

Comment: how then would you explain that enabling a monitor and saving a new xorg.conf via nvidia-settings makes all styling disappear? (and replaced by a dump default grey style)